Estoy teniendo problemas a la hora de eliminar un usuario en 2 stub diferentes
Tengo un tester que me muestra el siguiente resultado:
user1* se logea en dos stub, stub1 y stub2, en uno se borra y en otro no debe permitir hacer nada.
Result admin login (exp true): true
Result admin create user1 (exp true): true
Result user1 login (exp true): true
Result user1 login en otro stub (exp true): true
Result user1 deletes user1 en stub1 (exp true): true
Result user login en stub2 (exp false): true
Fail

y tengo el siguiente coódigo:
public RemoveUserResponse removeUser(RemoveUser removeUser) throws RemoteException {
    System.out.println("Iniccio de removeUser");
    Response responseXsd = new Response();
    responseXsd.setResponse(false);    
    RemoveUserResponse response = new RemoveUserResponse();    
      // Si el usuario no se ha logeado, devolvemos false
    if (usuario_logeado == null) {
        System.out.println("Usuario no logeado");
        response.set_return(responseXsd);
        return response;
    }    
    String nombre_logeado = usuario_logeado.getName();
    String nombre_eliminar = removeUser.getArgs0().getUsername();    
    System.out.println("Nombre logeado: " + nombre_logeado);
    System.out.println("Nombre eliminar: " + nombre_eliminar);    
      // Comprobamos si el usuario logeado es el admin
    if (!nombre_logeado.equals(nombre_admin)) {
          // En caso de no ser admin, comprobamos si el usuario a eliminar es el mismo que llama a removeUser
        if (!nombre_logeado.equals(nombre_eliminar)) {
            System.out.println("No es admin y no es el mismo usuario");
            // No puedes eliminar a otro usuario sin ser admin.
            response.set_return(responseXsd);
            return response;
        }
    }    
      // El admin no puede eliminarse a sí mismo
    if (nombre_logeado.equals(nombre_admin) && nombre_eliminar.equals(nombre_admin)) {
        System.out.println("El admin no puede eliminarse a si mismo");
        response.set_return(responseXsd);
        return response;
    }    
    synchronized (this) {
          // Verificar si el usuario existe
        if (!usuarios.containsKey(nombre_eliminar)) {
            System.out.println("El usuario no existe");
            response.set_return(responseXsd);
            return response;
        }
          // Llamar a eliminarUsuario del servicio
        boolean eliminadoExternamente = eliminarUsuario(nombre_eliminar);
        responseXsd.setResponse(eliminadoExternamente);
        System.out.println("Eliminado usuario del servicio");    
          // En caso de no poderse eliminar en el servicio
        if (!eliminadoExternamente) {
            System.out.println("No se ha podido eliminar el usuario del servicio");
            response.set_return(responseXsd);
            return response;
        }    
          // Actualizar el estado del sistema
        if (nombre_logeado.equals(nombre_eliminar)) {
            usuario_logeado = null;
            this.cuentas_activas = 0;
            System.out.println("Usuario eliminado del sistema");
        }    
          // Eliminar de la lista de seguidores
        if (seguidores.containsKey(nombre_eliminar)) {
            List<String> listaSeguidores = seguidores.get(nombre_eliminar);
            for (String seguidor : listaSeguidores) {
                List<String> sList = seguidores.get(seguidor);
                sList.remove(nombre_eliminar);
                System.out.println("Eliminado seguidor de la lista de seguidores");
            }
            seguidores.remove(nombre_eliminar);
        }    
          // Eliminar usuario
        usuarios.remove(nombre_eliminar);            
        System.out.println("Usuario eliminado del sistema");    
    }    
    responseXsd.setResponse(true);
    response.set_return(responseXsd);
    return response;
}

También esta función auxiliar:
public static boolean eliminarUsuario(String name) throws RemoteException {
    WSSkeletonStub stub = new WSSkeletonStub();
    WSSkeletonStub.RemoveUser eliminado = new WSSkeletonStub.RemoveUser();
    
    eliminado.setName(name);
    RemoveUserE eliminar = new RemoveUserE();
    eliminar.setRemoveUser(eliminado);
    
    RemoveUserResponseE response = stub.removeUser(eliminar);
    return  response.get_return().getResult();
}

No se exactamente donde puede estar el error, entiendo que lo que se debería hacer es que cuando se elimina a un usuario del sistema con un stub debería de eliminarse también para los demás stub.
